# Asp net core web api integration test - WebApplicationFactory - The entry point exited without ever building an IHost

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm creating integration test, but has need for override couple of things of default api startup

So i have created classess:

```
internal class ApiTestsBasicFactory: WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
}



public class TestStartup : Startup
    {
        public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
        {
        }

        protected override void AddDbContext(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>();
        }

        protected override void AddIdentity(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TestDbContext>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureBackgroundTasksDI(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

and i have class which is derived by multiple test classesss

```
private ApiTestsBasicFactory _factory;
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void GivenARequestToTheController()
{
    _factory = new ApiTestsBasicFactory();
    _client = _factory.CreateClient();
}
```

but when i run test, i have following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entry point exited without ever
> building an IHost.'

on this moment

[image]

tried also this:

```
  public void GivenARequestToTheController()
    {
        _factory = new ApiTestsBasicFactory();

        _client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseStartup<TestStartup>();
        }).CreateClient();


        //_client = _factory.CreateClient();
    }
```

but same result.

when i override CreateHostbuilder method on TestStartup

```
internal class ApiTestsBasicFactory : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
        

    webBuilder.UseStartup<TestStartup>();
        });

    return builder;
}
```

}

i always receive 404 response from my server (inside test)

what should i do to make it work correctly?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any new information or solutions?